# Cron task starts at 5:30 and runs every 5 mins once

Tags: cron

I want to run a crontab cron job which start at 5:30 AM and runs every 5 mins. How do i set it up in Linux?

I am able to give like below. But how do i make it 5:30 ?

```
*/05 5-16 * * *
```

Comment: If you see my code, it ends at 4 PM

Comment: Actually the last run will start at 5 minutes to 5 PM. When it ends depends on how long it runs.

Answer (score 2):

The `*/05` will match 5:00, 5:05 as well. You should make two entries:

```
30,35,40,45,50,55 5 * * *
*/05 6-16 * * *
```

(assuming you want it to run until 16:55 every five minutes after 5:30)

Alternatively you can use your original crontab entry and smarten up the script that is being called, to exit when run before 05:30.

Comment: just want to understand small thing. if i specify 6-16 will it run at 16:06,16:10 until 16:55 also ??

Comment: Yes. The first field matches the minutes, the second the hours. If you specify 6-16 for the hours and */5 for minutes then 16:05, 16:10, .. 16:55 matches the combination. I already commented on that below your original question.